# Добавить элементы в результат поиска компонента bitrix:search.page

Tags: битрикс

Есть компонент bitrix:search.page,у него есть встроенная пагинация ("DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "Y"). Можно ли как то к результатам поиска добавить свои элементы,чтобы они учитывались при построении пагинации?

Answer (score 0):

Создается файл result_modifier.php рядом с файлом template.php компонента. В нем можно редактировать массив $arResult перед выводом, дописать в него что-то

в первой строке файла должно быть

```
<?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();
```